# Hibernate Configuration Loading Error

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I am trying to create a simple hibernate project, but I am getting error while reading hibernate.cfg.xml file, dont know what the issue is, below is the code and error trace. Please help.

**Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml file:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

   <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EPS</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">haris</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">ihatecookies</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop or re-create database -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <!-- Mapping files -->
        <mapping class="com.secure.eps.model.User"/>        

    </session-factory> 
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Here is my main class:**

```
package com.secure.eps.controller;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.secure.eps.model.User;

public class HibernateUtil {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername("RoojiPooji");
        user.setPassword("ihatecookies");

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.configure().buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

    }

}
```

**Here is error stack:**

```
Sep 24, 2014 9:37:41 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Sep 24, 2014 9:37:41 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
Sep 24, 2014 9:37:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.h2.Driver, hibernate.service.allow_crawling=false, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect, hibernate.max_fetch_depth=5, hibernate.format_sql=true, hibernate.generate_statistics=true, hibernate.connection.username=sa, hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=TRUE, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true, hibernate.connection.pool_size=5}
Sep 24, 2014 9:37:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Sep 24, 2014 9:37:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Sep 24, 2014 9:37:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2163)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2075)
    at com.secure.eps.controller.HibernateUtil.main(HibernateUtil.java:19)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: null Nested exception: null
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2155)
    ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is an issue with this line in your xml configuration.

```
    <!-- Mapping files -->
    <mapping class="com.secure.eps.model.User"/>
```

Refer to hibernate docs: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_mapping_files.htm.

Comment: No thats not it, You can map an entity inside hibernate-configuration file aswell.

Comment: Try removing the String you passed into the Configuration.configure() method. It should be looking for an application resource "hibernate.cfg.xml" by default. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Strange, I reproduced and it worked perfectly fine for me. Maybe it's a dependency issue. What JARS+versions do you have in your classpath?